# Auto-decline questions with excessive profanity

Tags: feature-request, offensive, quality-filter

Some things in questions are hard to catch programmatically. However, certain questions are plain and obvious when it comes to *what's not okay*.

This user seems to have found a (temporary) home here on SO posting *'copypasta'* material.

While I'm not suggesting we track every kind of copypasta on the internet (that'd require too much time on 4Chan) this kind of post could have triggered at least one programmatic red-flag.

There *has* to be a way to detect these kinds of questions before they're posted.

[image]

Comment: Gorilla Warfare sounds like a show I'd watch.

Comment: @AdamLear That guy has a chimp on his shoulder.

Comment: I like the [tag:swagger] tag.

Comment: Damn, we will never know what prompted that outburst. :(

Comment: Wait a sec: while we might find this humorous and a little far-fetched, this particular user is making death threats against another. I don't mean to sound alarmist but none of us on our worst day would even come close to sounding like that.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/navy-seal-copypasta

Comment: Ah @BoltClock...heh.

Comment: Notice the tags: PHP and swagger. Why does that seem like more than a coincidence? :P

Comment: They're definitely opposites.

Comment: Gorilla warfare is no monkey business, you know!

Comment: I'm amazed somebody didn't try and edit it adding some carriage returns, that would of been worth 2 rep, yo!

Comment: Flag --- not a question.

Comment: @Louis What about chimps on shoulders ?

Comment: I'm amazed anyone even noticed the copypasta.. I would've close-voted just from the title!

Comment: @dystroy I was making a pun on the basis of [this phrase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chip_on_shoulder). "Chip" -> "chimp". I see in your avatar you've got a monkey (of species that I can't determine; macaque?) on your back.

Comment: I like the lone downvote.

Comment: @Jigg I caught the screenshot seconds before it plummeted to -7.

Comment: Technically, this could be catched via an OCR ;) Even the ugly hacks around it could be somewhat catched. However it's not feasible yet.

Comment: Only one downvote?  Sounds like the community still likes this question more than ones about `NullPointerException`s.  Trollface.jpg

Comment: It did Ali Gajani, it did.

Comment: Meh, it's got the terms "Al-Quaeda" "wipes out" "the Entire US Armed Forces"... so who needs a profanity filter, just let the NSA mop it up. I'm sure they have his Mom's phone tapped already.

Comment: I hope no innocent gorilla would be hurt in the droning process...

Answer (score 214, accepted):

What the ƒuck did you just ƒucking say about me, you little ßitch? I'll have you know I graduated [top of my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/css/topusers) on the Stack Overflow Q&A site, and I've been involved in numerous secret raids on the Suggested Edits queue, and [I have over 300 confirmed edit rejections](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4915920). I am trained in Stack Exchange Q&A and [I'm the top user by reputation in the entire Stack Overflow moderation team](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)<sup>1</sup>. You are nothing to me but just another new user. I will wipe you the ƒuck out with precision the likes of which has never been seen before on this site, mark my ƒucking words. You think you can get away with saying that sћit to me over the Internet? Think again, ƒucker. As we speak I am contacting my secret network of community managers across the network and your IP is being traced right now so you better prepare for the storm, unestablished user. The storm that wipes out the pathetic little thing you call your question. You're ƒucking hobbled, kid. I can be anywhere, anytime, and I can ban you in exactly one way, and that's just with the click of a button. Not only am I extensively trained in button-clicking, but I have access to the entire arsenal of all pointing devices ever invented and I will use it to its full extent to wipe your miserable account off the face of the site, you little sћit. If only you could have known what unholy retribution your little "clever" question was about to bring down upon you, maybe you would have held your ƒucking tongue. But you couldn't, you didn't, and now you're paying the price, you godd@mn id|ot. I will sћit diamonds all over you and you will drown in them. You're ƒucking destroyed, kiddo.

---

For those who don't get it:

- [The copypasta in question](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/navy-seal-copypasta)
- [Tom Christiansen on why trying to implement a profanity filter is a Bad Idea™](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6096634/regular-expression-preg-quote-symbols-are-not-detected/6099598#6099598)

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>[Not anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results), but this was true at the time this was posted. I am proud as ƒuck to call myself a veteran.</sub>

Comment: You win. I'm done.

Comment: `I have access to the entire arsenal of all pointing devices ever invented`

Comment: You're supposed to use [unicode](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6099598/922184) spellings. :)

Comment: hilarious! `:)`

Comment: @Mysticial Boltclock actually commented on that answer hahaha

Comment: @Mysticial: I actually happen to remember *exactly* how I worked around the filters back then - going to do the same here.

Comment: Yeah now that I've posted this, memories of filter-dodging on Runescape started pouring in.

Comment: Now THAT's more like it! :D:D:D

Comment: Poetry.  Bobince [would be proud](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/102937).

Comment: "BoltClock has approved 1428 edit suggestions and rejected 383 edit suggestions" WHAT?! If you weren't a mod, I'd flag you for robo-approving. You should be rejecting *half* of edits… not something to be bragging about. *I* have rejected 446 edits - that's 74 times more considering rep.

Comment: @bjb568 Please don't confuse robo-reviewing with someone who approves more than rejects. A robo-reviewer is someone who doesn't even look at what they are doing. Someone who approves most edits is probably one who skips most of them.

Comment: @Mystical Hehe, I know. I just like to accuse mods.

Comment: Feature request: let me favourite answers :) (but AFAIK this has already been declined...)

Comment: I want has sћit diamonds all over me please!

Comment: You should run this through a spell checker. Oh, perhaps a request for all posts to automatically run through spell and grammer (sic) check.

Comment: First time I accidentally read the name as "BoltCock". Was disappointed because at first sight it was much more funny.

Comment: How long did it take to write this answer vs how long did it take the poster of the question in question to copypast it? Forcing time-wasters to spend some time themselves is a modest win, and preventing anyone writing either "goddamn" or "godd@mn" isn't AFAIK the goal. That's not to say the proposed feature is a good idea, but I don't think this is the reason it isn't.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: True (I upvoted your comment), but I never intended to provide a serious argument in the first place :) If you ask me, I honestly don't think that modest win is worth going through the trouble to implement something that's going to be so trivial for most people to bypass anyway. As already mentioned, the community is well-equipped to handle these posts after the fact in any case.

Comment: @SargeBorsch Wow, that's how i've always read it. D:

Comment: @BoltClock Ne'er did I think this would be the answer to earn you a gold badge.

Comment: W̛͕̯͍͔ha̮̪̳̘͔ͅṭ̳͖̹͙ ͖t̺͕̙͎h̼̯̲e͔̳̹͇̺̕ ̲͎͕̖ͅƒ͔̳̲̮͔̠̖͡u͔̼͜c͔͖̯̭̹̗̮k͖͖̤̫̕ d̹̭̜͟į̹̰̫̤d̯ ̙̻̟̲̲y̳̜̯o̬̬̲̝͇͙ų j̗͔̪̪u̠͚̰̠͎̺̮s̹t̪͔͓͓͚ ̲͎͕ƒ͎͈̩̘u͍̘̭͕̹͝c̪̙̮̫̳ͅki̷̮n̸͚̝̰͙̘̼̬g̶̫͚̳̼̻̯̦ ̥̻̼ͅs͙̯̱̩͙͙͕ą̝͕̝̘̻y ̺̦̺̩͇̳a̫̳͠ͅb̳̳̳̥͈̀o͏̳͓͙ut́ ̵͚͇͓̲m̞͉̮̥̲̕e̪̹͜,̝̭͝ ̴̳̟͕̭͚ͅy̙̟͈̻͎͚͎o̘u̙͢ ̷l͓̼̼͙̬̝i̤̤̹͈̯̠͠ͅt̻̘͜t̙͙͉̳̲͈l̩̭͓̮e̱͕ ̶̮͚ß̡͈͕̰̩̥͉i̷t͈̱̫͡c̯̭̱̗͡h̢͇̺͚?̱̖͈̹ͅ

Comment: And you can always do f***. What's the point? The whole idea is to catch some, not all. And "some" would in this case be profanities with ASCII characters.

Comment: One can also use word replacement. `Alpha Q Up little Beach`

Comment: "Not only am I extensively trained in button-clicking [...]" gonna print and frame that one.

Comment: Sorry I don't have enough "points" to DownVote anything at the moment!

Answer (score 37):

There are a couple of problems with profanity filters:

1. The [clbuttic problem](http://blog.codinghorror.com/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea/),
2. Legitimate profanity in code (y'know, profanity filters).
3. [Easily defeated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256534/102937).

Profanity, spam and the like already get dispatched very quickly.  I'd say the system works as is.

Comment: The clbuttic problem isn't what I'm suggesting. That's talking about a filter - i.e. translating one swear word into a more 'prude-friendly' word (i.e. `clASSic` -> `clBUTTic`). I'm suggesting **deny the post altogether** if they reach a profanity count of >X (this user would have tipped the scales).

Comment: Well there would be a minimum count of course but I see your point.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I see no reason whatsoever that the specific inputs to a profanity filter can't be abstracted away, resulting in a question about replacing arbitrary text in other arbitrary text. In fact, that would make it a better question overall, anyway.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Could be, but since questions like this are relatively rare, and already get dispatched very quickly anyway...

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Yeah I was only responding to your comment, not proposing the addition of a profanity filter to SO.

Comment: clbuttic reminds me of the old efnet forums where everybody was talking about "Pregnant Dog X"...

Comment: Legitimate profanity in code `=>` [Brainfuck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck).

Answer (score 31):

Maybe instead of having questions with excess profanity automatically declined, they should  go into the low quality posts review queue (or a different review queue) for humans to review whether they are okay or whether the post is poorly written and/or not fitting for the site. Maybe it's not possible to automatically detect every single instance of going out of one's way to intentionally throw in profanity with unicode substitutions, but it'd probably catch some posts. Perhaps if a post has a certain number of probably profane words, it triggers the post to go in a review queue...and it makes the site a little bit better, even if it's not perfect.

Comment: Feeding them into low quality posts review would be fine. There might even already be heuristics in place for detecting such things, but of course we don't know all the details...

Answer (score 6):

[Here's another reason why this filter cannot be instated.](https://www.google.com/webhp?complete=1&hl=en#complete=1&hl=en&q=site:stackoverflow.com%20cunt)

There are gems such as:

```
self.cunt.Insert(val, 0)
```

Or this legitimate question title:

> Pandas and sum and cum [...]

(Title shortened to make the point.)

Comment: Though I presume [that is an unfortunately named variable of the OP's own choosing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22871832/73226)

Comment: Oh yeah, we wouldn't want to keep questions [like that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22871832/how-to-assign-different-functions-to-different-tree-selections-in-the-below-give) out! No way!

Comment: Is Pandas a profanity? I thought they are cute...

Comment: Albeit another poor question: [if (cock != 'null') cock.split(';');](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19974536/works-in-jfiddle-but-not-in-browser)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the given text is not the profanity, but the lack of any sense.

Unfortunatelly, it's currently impossible to create any automatic filter that would detect sense or the lack therof. Although the straw man's observation suggest, that individuals using excessive amount of profanity tend to sparingly deal with sense in their statements, there are very many examples of texts completely lacking both.

The profanity filter is also useless in fighting kitchen spam, homework assignments and other common plagues. It would be optimizing system agaist single case. Not a very good idea.

Answer (score -1):

I think it doesn't take a highly reputed member just to remove this from further circulation, I mean option for deleting obvious spam/copypasta should be given to reasonably low reputation member to stop waste of resources.

Comment: All it takes is [15 reputation to be able to flag posts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).