# April 2015 Community Moderator Election RESULTS

Tags: discussion, moderator-election, moderator-resignation

Stack Overflow's [6th moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 3 new moderators are:

[image: meagar] [image: Martijn Pieters] [image: Jeremy Banks]

They'll be joining [the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/election/6), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4962933813542912/0).

Oh, and one more thing...

### After six years of service, Bill the Lizard gets to be a normal user.

[image: Bill the Lizard]

New moderators on Stack Overflow always have a lot to live up to, but never before have they had such big shoes to fill: veteran moderator [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) has announced that he'll be stepping down in May.

[Bill and Marc Gravell were the first two moderators](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/welcome-new-community-moderators/) elected on Stack Overflow, and in many ways Bill has been *the* archetype for what a moderator on Stack Exchange should be. His patient, fair and calm demeanor even in the face of criticism is legendary; his diligence and skill in handling the numerous difficult problems that face Stack Overflow users are inspiring. For the past 6 years, Bill has been an example for new moderators to follow, his impressive record a lofty goal to strive for. I honestly can't imagine what Stack Overflow would be like today without Bill.

Bill has graciously agreed to stay on for a little while yet to help the newly-elected moderators get up to speed. I strongly encourage them to take full advantage of this opportunity.

For the rest of you, please join me in thanking Bill for the tremendous work he has done here, and wishing him all the best as he returns to life as a respected member of the community.

Comment: <acceptance speech here>

Comment: We'll miss you Bill! Congrats to the new mods!

Comment: Congratulations to those three winners, and thank you Bill for all you have done in all those years (welcome back to the *normal users* ;P)

Comment: Yeeees. When Jeremy elected himself, I thought he'd never win because he was so modest. I voted for him, and I'm glad to see he won.

Comment: I think you vastly understimated the number of (human) mods needed to replace Bill the Lizard ;-)

Comment: Thank you Bill. Congrats new mods :)

Comment: Congrats all! Gonna flag some stuff to get you started :p

Comment: Congratulations to everyone that was elected!  And Bill, thanks for your service to the community.  It was much appreciated.

Comment: I'm glad to be part of a web community that can decide moderators through peaceful elections as opposed to bloody coup's

Comment: Congratulations all - this is a wonderful group!

Comment: Congratulations to the winners! Thanks for your hard work, Bill the Lizard!

Comment: Congrats everybody! That was a super fun election.

Comment: Congratulations guys, it was an honor to race with you. Thanks to everyone who supported me, I was overwhelmed by the positive feedback. But the best candidates certainly have won.

Comment: Congratulations to everyone! (Eagerly awaiting your next nomination, @deceze!)

Comment: Is this going to be the fastest ever post voting?

Comment: Hey @deceze don't worry, you'll still get my vote if we're lucky enough to see your candidature next year. By the way, congrats to the elected ones :-)

Comment: Maybe Bill can keep the diamond, even if he isn't on that often. Just in case, just to see how it feels. I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Guess I'll have to come back then... :o)

Comment: I love to see my two favorite candidates made it up in the election! Thank you @BillTheLizard (I already mentioned some day [I love lizards & geckos and why](http://dev-jungle.blogspot.de/p/blog-page.html)). You've been a big ideal for moderation. Have a good time!

Comment: Congrats, folks! Bill, job very well done! I've always appreciated your modding. You modded good...you modded real good. But welcome back to the peasant side :P

Comment: Two out of three ain't bad.  Congrats to you suckers!

Comment: Great to have you three on board! Bill, as a relative newcomer around these parts I'm still learning just how much you've affected the corner of the internet I work on each day. Thank you for everything.

Comment: Easiest gold badge ever earned. ;)

Comment: Congratulations to you all ! And all of you who didn't quite make it, we look forward to seeing your nominations next year ! @deceze, I'd love to see you moderating on the soon-to-be German SO !

Comment: Congratulations to new Mods, SO can grow while in your hands!!

Comment:  we'll miss u Bill!

Comment: Cheers Bill.  We appreciate all the work you've put in keeping SO a good place to be.

Comment: @MillieSmith Modesty is widely considered a *good* quality in a mod. :) But most of the candidates this year expressed modest attitudes. To me what stood out about Jeremy Banks is that the issues he most emphasized are what I consider arguably the biggest problems at SO: Being too hasty to close questions as dupes of questions that don't really address what's being asked, and "answering legitimate questions with 'you're doing it wrong' and challenging the premise instead of being helpful."

Comment: @AdiInbar Some comments on Jeremy's nomination (he deleted some of his comments): "That's my point, you need a change of attitude. I.e., You will most definitely, without a doubt get the job done" by Marcus. "This is bizarre. Did Jeremy leave his computer logged in while he was in the shower?" by Chris Baker. "Updated the post. I have reflected and decided that I would be a useful and effective moderator." by Jeremy. He was being modest and the community thought he was crazy for it. I was fine with it, if not happy, but his approach is not usually rewarded on the high stage.

Comment: We should make Bill a part time mod.

Comment: Holy crap, Martijn killed it...

Comment: Shog, please accept Bill's answer so that it stays on the top. It deserves the top position.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: OPs are not obligated to accept answers regardless of anyone else's opinions. Go stand in the corner!

Comment: @BoltClock: The OP is new on SO and may not be aware of the green checkmark, so I am helping him.

Comment: @Infinite Recursion: Nice save.

Comment: Congrats to the new moderators and Thank you Bill for your service !!!

Comment: all the best to the new moderators.. :D Thanks Bill for your help for 6 years

Comment: Congratulations to those three winners!

Comment: congrates all of you guys. Hope you all will be great here :)

Comment: Congrats new moderators. It was indeed an honour to race with all the candidates. Thanks to all the community members for the supports. Looking forward to the next election :)

Comment: Congratulation to the new moderators and glad that two of them whom i voted became a moderator :-) Thank you **Bill the Lizard** for taking care of this community. All the best for your future . :-) And all the best to the newly elected moderators.

Comment: @Jonas Hmm, to be honest, I have no clue how to talk about technical topics *in German*. All my lingo has been built up in English and I have real problems expressing anything programming related in pure German. So, not sure about how much use a German SO will be to me...

Comment: @Travis Anarchists... anti-democracy... ;)

Comment: Welcome, newly elected mods! Thank you, Bill (not for leaving, of course, but for the service offered in these years)!

Comment: Thank you a million times Bill, SO is invaluable and your unselfish dedication of time has resulted in saving time for so many of us. The most precious commodity.

Comment: Congrats, @meagar and thanks for [already using your diamond to help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29782039/how-to-insert-empty-rows-under-all-already-occupied-rows-simultaneously-in-goo#comment47702702_29782039)!

Comment: Good Luck Bill ! You have worked too hard to get those points between ;) that isnt easy for me !

Comment: congrats friends..happy to see this..do the best

Comment: Congratulations!!! @Martijn Pieters Not anymore [ninja](http://cdn.smosh.com/sites/default/files/legacy.images/smosh-pit/032011/ninja-surprise.gif); the diamond is now visible to everyone ;)

Comment: Does the avatar match the nickname or does the nickname match the avatar?

Comment: Commiserations @deceze, you had my vote. Congrats to the others - two out of three ain't bad.

Comment: <s>Just one question here; what's with the ordering of newly elected moderators?</s> They are in descending order of `UserID`s

Comment: -1... I just like to different. :-) Nah, Well done everyone and thank you Bill the Lizard for all your hard work.

Comment: It may not be worth an own question, but maybe someone stumbles upon this: The opavote site says "The number of votes is 27019 and there were 27019 valid votes." - how could a vote have been "invalid"? (I assume that this is just an artifact of the hosting site, isn't it?)

Comment: Congratulations all and goodluck Bill!

Comment: The posts on this page is a reminder of how awesome the SO community really is.

Comment: Congrats to all the runners-up! All the best luck to new moderators (which i am happily to say that got my votes, all 3 of them) :)

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators, and a great thank you along with wishes for the best to Bill the Lizard!

Comment: Congrats to the new mods ... I did not have enough rep points to vote but followed the elections none the less. Reading their campaign posts was very interesting. A big thank you to Bill the Lizard too.

Comment: Every article that argues "against" Stackoverflow all name Bill the Lizard as the moderator that they encountered in their "bad experience". Well done for keeping the site clean :)

Comment: Let's make a grayed-out (meaning: inactive control ;-) ) diamond for Bill, symbolizing his ex-moderator status. This should be used for other ex-mods as well...

Comment: Congratulations to the new moderators! And Bill: you'll find good use for the extra hours of spare time and you deserve it :-)

Comment: Congrats! I hope you will take SO to a higher level ;)

Comment: Big congratulations to the new moderators, especially @meager and Martin. Finally, a big Thank You to Bill the Lizard for his many years of service. I remember Bill from way back in 2008 or 2009. I'm sure being a mod is not the least bit easy, so thanks again Bill!

Comment: Thank you and Salute Bill the Lizard! Congratulations to the new party members!!

Comment: The vote results are so bizzare... here's my suggestion for next time. Let all users vote. One user = one vote. Count the votes. The 3 candidates with most votes win. I believe this method of voting is called "democracy" :)

Comment: We always gonna miss you  .. @Bill The Lizard

Comment: Congrats to the new mods :-)

Comment: Congratulations to the newly elected mods whom I someday home to join as well as Bill the Lizard for his years of service.

Comment: Congratulations to everyone that was elected! Bill, Ton of thanks for your dynamic service to the SO .(y)

Comment: Congrats to the new ones and thanks to Bill and also to anyone contributing to this great community.

Comment: Congrats to the new team. Thanks to Bill, for your service.

Comment: congrats to the newly elected team.

Comment: Congratulations New Moderators :) Thank you Bill :)

Comment: First of all, my congratulation and best wishes for the newly elected moderators. This is going to be a tough, demanding job. Good luck and don't forget to keep seeing the fun of it. As for Bill, there is not much left to say. However, I'd suggest to further grant him administrative *rights* without *obligations* except for obeying the rules (Heck, he did write some of them, didn't he?). His skill and experience might well still be helpful and maybe he will help out here and there during his visits.

Comment: I'm skeptical of users having twice as many downvotes cast as upvotes simply because it would _appear_ that they care more about knocking users down rather than trying to build them up.  In the case of really terrible questions, why bother downvoting them at all when they should just be closed and deleted?

Comment: Congratulations, guys.  Condolences, too :-)

Comment: Congratulations guys

Comment: **After six years of service, Bill the Lizard gets to be a normal user** – Impossible ! you are a Superhero

Comment: congrats to new mods and bill yes you will be missed for sure..

Comment: Congo...Hope now there will be new rules which will help new users like me..:)

Comment: Congrats Guys..All the very best..:-)

Comment: that post edit history though ^_^

Comment: I will miss Bill The Crocodile :(

Comment: Who in their right mind downvotes this kind of stuff?

Comment: @jakekimds - ah...I think I see...yes, your confusion comes from an over-generalization of the applicability of the term "in their right mind"... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis Are you saying most people here are not in their right mind?

Comment: @jakekimds - no, what I meant was that it appeared you were applying the term "in their right minds" in reference to "downvoters" (of this question). I did not mean to question the sanity of the general population of StackOverflow enthusiasts...although, y'know, now that you mention it... :-)

Comment: I'm not that old reg here, but I wish I could one day get more experience and skills to step up as a moderator and be as amazing as bill was. way to go new mods!

Comment: @U9-Forward (for the initial 'edit') and the ones afterwards quibbling over that full stop: .... *really?*

Answer (score 1103, accepted):

First and foremost I'd like to say congratulations to the newly elected moderators. I'm tempted to say that I'm sorry that we won't work together for very long, but given your nearly 6,000 combined flags and various Meta contributions, I'd say we've been working together for a while now. Thank you all for volunteering.

---

Six years is a long time, especially in Internet years. Now is a good time for me to step down as moderator for a couple of reasons.

1. I'm thinking of making a small career course correction soon, and it's going to take a lot of attention and focus to make it happen.
2. More importantly (to anyone reading this), there's never been a better group of moderators at Stack Overflow than right now. Some really great people have come and gone over the years, but the active group has steadily grown. There are a lot of really good, active moderators volunteering their time right now. With the addition of three new moderators, I know the existing mods can handle the burden of me stepping away.

I won't be stepping completely away from the community, though. I'll still be programming, so I'll have questions and answers for Stack Overflow. I also have a few side project ideas, some of which are related to Stack Exchange, so I'll still be posting here on Meta from time to time.

I'm really proud to have been so deeply involved in what I think is the best community on the web. Thank you all for letting me be your moderator for the past six years. I hope in my time here that I've helped to make our corner of the internet a little bit better.

Comment: Bill, I don't even know how to express my feels right now. You've been directly and indirectly a part of my formative SO/SE months and years, and I've learned a metric ton from you about moderation. Really, my only regret is finding out that you're not, in fact, a lizard. I hope to still see you around. Don't be a stranger. And above all, **thank you**.

Comment: @AnnaLear *"... you're not, in fact, a lizard."* Oh come on, how about a spoiler alert next time?

Comment: @JasonC [feature-request] spoiler markup in comments and we'll get to it. #NoPromises

Comment: Thank you, @AnnaLear. Sorry to disappoint you with my humanity. ;)

Comment: I regret to inform you that there is no Internet meme image that can adequately capture my feelings about this moment. EXCEPT THIS ONE http://i.imgur.com/GbEwBl0.jpg

Comment: Thank you and wish you all the very best in your life and career.

Comment: While I haven't been moderating with you as long as the other SO mods I can see why everyone looks to you for guidance.  You are always polite, level-headed and get straight to the point when it comes to handling things. I've enjoyed our time together and you will most definitely be missed.

Comment: You're awesome, and thanks a ton for how much of a better place Stack Overflow is because of you. Good luck with your future career-related endeavors, and again, thank you for how much you've contributed to the SO community and for being an amazing role model.

Comment: Thank you, @bluefeet. It hasn't been that long, but you are off to an amazing start! I've backed off a little bit from moderating this past year, and you're one of the people who really stepped up.

Comment: Thanks Bill! I know it takes a lot of effort to keep up the level of involvement you have maintained over the years. I would also implore you to request that you keep your diamond as an honorary moderator. :)

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Thank you and wish you good luck for your future. Have a wonderful life.

Comment: @JeffAtwood That's really ironic considering how many of my screw-ups you had to fix back in the middle part of 2009. A lot of people have been thanking me and praising me today for setting a good example, but you're really the one who set the standards back then with your blog posts and the occasional "WTF happened here?" email. Thank you for being patient when showing Marc and I the ropes. I'm really happy to have passed your great example on to others.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: [But I...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121595/thank-you-jeff-atwood/121750#121750)

Comment: @TravisJ Thank you, but no, I can't resist the siren call of the moderator queue. I need to remove the distraction. Besides, I'm looking forward to being just a regular member of the community again.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thank you for all those years of service. 
I do hope that you continue to contribute with questions/answers/comments. See you around!

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your great service. Recently i come to know how does stackoverflow works and now i am contributing my efforts, by reading your post and the wishes for you by other contributors, i wondered, and now  think i missed those great years where i could contribute my part under care of you. I would say that stay touched with stackoverflow and help us to learn more :)

Comment: It wouldn't be the same if you weren't here. Thank you Bill!

Comment: You users better upvote this answer!

Comment: You are awesome.

Comment: Can confirm about Bill's help. He was in several of my question topics a couple days ago..  Thanks Bill!

Comment: So... are you missing it yet?  The inability to instaclose crap is the hardest part of giving up mod superpowers, imho.

Comment: @Will Yes, just *voting* to close sucks! And now I have to *reply* to comments instead of deleting them?

Comment: A BIG Thank You for Mr Bill and good luck for the new moderators

Comment: Thank you for your service to the community, Bill.

Comment: _Hey! Who called [the cops](http://i.imgur.com/2fmrTCW.png)!_ Anyway, thanks for the great job you've done on this site. Best of luck! :-)

Comment: @BilltheLizard Just saw this. As someone who has over the years benefited indirectly from all your hard work as a SO moderator, I'd like to say thanks.

Comment: @williamdnapier You're welcome. I was happy to do it.

Answer (score 285):

I just wanted to say this: Bill has been a role model for me and my actions on this site.

When I started to care more about the moderation side of things, I began reading posts on the then-new Meta.SO. Things were a little more free-form back then, but I remember always being impressed with how polite and to the point Bill was in his answers and comments. Even when people called him out or insulted him, he stayed calm and constructive.

I decided to pattern my own responses on that, and I feel I became a better contributor because of it. I don't think I would have even cared about becoming a moderator if I didn't have that example to draw from.

It's going to be a long while before someone catches up to the total number of flags he's handled, yet how many times have people complained about his actions on Meta? That tells you something about his judgment and knowledge of the community.

In many ways, I think Bill set the tone for all moderators on Stack Overflow, and the site would be a very different place without his influence.

Thanks, [lizard man](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748531/how-to-be-good-as-me).

[image]

Comment: Haha, that [lizard man](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14748531/how-to-be-good-as-me) QA is hilarious *how to be **as** good as me*. An easter egg among mod's.

Comment: Awh, that question got deleted :(

Comment: @SantaClaus here you go http://i.stack.imgur.com/xaBRP.png screen shot of that page :)

Comment: Thank you, Brad. I'm really proud that someone like you would call me a role model. You've been an exemplary member of the community for as long as I can remember, and I always knew you'd be a great moderator. (Maybe not as good as 'Bill Woo Upgrade', but who is? It would take 100 years at least to be as good as that guy!)

Comment: @NullPoiиteя how many upvotes does it have? Just curious.

Comment: @jakekimds Just 1.

Comment: @NullPoiиteя How is Bill "The lizard" as a person. I would like to see his real face. An awesome Mod . :)

Answer (score 213):

#### Thank you, Bill the Lizard!

I first noticed you in late 2008, not long after I joined. Your name showed that you didn't take yourself too seriously, yet your answers were always quality. You were always patient and never seemed to get into a comment war (which was a somewhat rare quality in those wild west days).

This exchange in the first Stack Overflow election blog post is one of my favorites:

> Bill the Lizard [May 6 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/stack-overflow-moderator-voting-now-open/#comment-21366)
>   Jon Ericson,
>   Since you brought it up, I might as well come right out and say that that is my real name and picture. I thought you’d all like to know that for the past several months you’ve been taking the advice of a cartoon lizard. I hope that doesn’t change the way anyone votes.
>
> Shog9 May 6 2009
>   Wow… Now i wish i’d voted for Bill…

[I voiced my objection](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/stack-overflow-moderator-voting-now-open/#comment-21844) on the grounds that the person who posted [Jon Skeet Facts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts) shouldn't be the one deciding which questions were closed. But that turned out not to be a problem once we got a better hold on what to do with such questions.

When I became a moderator a little over a year later, I learned the ropes by clicking on a flag and then refreshing until you did something. It almost always worked. I'd like to cite your flag handling numbers here since they deserve to be public, but you handled so many it literally broke the moderator stats page.<sup>1</sup>

This is a close approximation to Bill's work in the mod queue:

[image]

Farewell, and don't be a stranger!

---

<sup>1</sup>Sources say the real figure is somewhere between 400000 and 500000. That's still a lot.

Comment: Half a MILLION flags? zomg.

Comment: Here I am thinking *raising* five thousand or so (helpful) flags is something of an accomplishment to work toward. *Handling* two orders of magnitude more than that? Man. That's staggering.

Comment: I remember writing that blog comment! I'm still convinced that joke is what got me enough votes to get elected mod in the first place. Also, I want to say thank you for moderating for nearly five years yourself. It's been a pleasure working with you.

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Needless to say, I was proven as wrong as possible. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 125):

I'd like to add my voice to the thanks for Bill filling the role of moderator on Stack Overflow so admirably.

Bill has always been the voice of reason and, like the others have said, his actions are the standard we all strive for.

It's been a pleasure working with him electronically and I can only lament the fact that we are different continents which makes an actual meeting somewhat problematic.

Comment: Thank you, Chris. You're probably the one person who's the most respected and admired across the network for your level-headedness and good judgement, so this means a lot to me coming from you. It was a real pleasure working with you. If I ever cross the pond, I'll be sure to look you up.

Comment: I'd be terrified if I knew there was a lizard coming for me... those things are unstoppable.

Comment: @BoltClock Understandable. I guess giant lizards are really not welcome in some parts of the world. ;p

Answer (score 85):

Like the others, Bill the Lizard was a role model and an inspiration to me, and he was one of the biggest reasons [I first nominated myself](https://stackoverflow.com/election/2#post-8043622).

Since my election, among fellow moderators he's probably been the one I've looked to the most whenever I had questions about using the moderation tools, or about handling specific problem users he may or may not be familiar with. I've only handled a paltry *tenth* of the flags he's handled (50k compared to his *half a million*) — despite having served for at least half the time that he has (little over three years compared to his six) — but much like Brad I probably never would have cared in the first place had Bill not been a source of inspiration. I could go so far as to say that Bill makes flag handling seem *fun*. At least, when it's not all mundane.

Last but certainly not least, I'm immensely grateful to Bill for [directly stepping in my defense that one time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network/126924#126924).

Thank you for everything, Bill!

Comment: Always glad to have your back! Also, I was reading back through the nominations from 2011 just now. Damn, that was a strong field! Just look at all the people who eventually became mods.

Answer (score 78):

[BilltheLizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard), am I happy about your departure?

[image]

I've not interacted with you often - just a few times, but I've seen that diamond appear on my screen and with your name next to it more times than I care to mention. Your contribution is nothing short of remarkable.

I voted for and welcome the new mods, but I know you will be sorely-missed and by many.

The very best for the future.

Answer (score 62):

I wanted to say a big **THANK YOU** to **ALL** the candidates who ran in the election. I thought that the general quality level of the candidates was very impressive, and that there were a bunch more beyond just the top 3 who would also have been very capable moderators. So thank you all for running, and giving us voters all the great options to choose from.

Also thanks to Bill the Lizard. While I never dealt with him directly, I noticed that his name showed up a lot when my flags were handled or clean up was done, so it was very clear that he was hard at work. And seeing how some of the most excellent moderators mention you as their role model speaks highly of your influence.

Apparently lizard pictures are now required in this thread. I just found a new one of Bill:

[image: Bill after retirement]

which looks like a nice change of pace from his more familiar pose:

[image: Bill as moderator]

Answer (score 52):

## Congrats to new mods! Welcome, you all to StackOverflow!! ;)

## TO:

[image: Bill the Lizard]

Best of luck with your new career and life. Wish you all the best. :)

[image]

Answer (score 44):

**Congrats to new mods!**

I didn't vote for all of you, but that's only because competition was very high and there was a tough choice with 3 votes and 12 great candidates.
Given different choices, I would have happily used my votes on any of you 3.

It is most certainly a welcomed and excellent outcome from the elections, and have no doubt you will all do a cracking job!

Congrats! :)

---

**Thank you Bob The Wizard**! You'll be missed by all of us who know you *very* well!

But on a serious note (Bill), while we've not really discussed much together so you won't know me, I have seen a *great deal* of your posts and actions.
And I have always found you to be quite pragmatic and affable, and to the point without being brusque.

A loss of a truly great moderator, and I imagine your approach over the years will have certainly helped shape SO to what it is today, especially from the butterfly effect!

I sincerely hope your new direction works out well for you.

[image: Bob the Wizard]

Comment: Bob the "Lizard"

Comment: "Bill" the Wizard

Comment: Well, yes, it's "Bill the Lizard", I was joking about not knowing his name ;)

Answer (score 42):

First of all to all of you...
[image]

[image: Martijn Pieters]

Many congrats to Martijn on being a moderation and also to other moderator.

I have seen Martijn on meta where he has participant as a reviewer actively that's why my vote goes to him.
I am happy that my vote goes to right candidate who is regular on SO.

**For Bill:**

[image: bill]

I am a member of SO from last 3 years and also seen Bill at many places like closing vote, mark as duplicate and many other activity to clean the So. That time I was not aware to this part (moderation) of SO. But by time, I understand the meaning of this. Now I am surprised that bill has spend 6 year as moderator, really a great work by a great person.

**Hats off to this guy.**
[image]

Hope he will give his valuable time continuously.

Best of luck for future!!!

Answer (score 36):

We will miss you, Bill the Lizard.

Welcome, new Stack Overflow moderators! May `${deity}` have mercy on your souls.

Comment: Oh come on, at least leave a comment stating how this answer could be improved...

Comment: We are missing [a picture](http://i.imgur.com/TCYPXQN.jpg)! :)

Comment: @bjb568 Dude, this is even ECMAScript 6! Forget about jQuery, he’s got template strings from the ES6 standard!

Comment: @Xufox It'll never be enough jquery. Even when the day arrives that all briwsers actually are following the ECMA Standards and not a single legacy browser is used anymore.. It still won't be enough jQuery

Comment: Maybe we can report this and Bill the Lizard will remove it.

Comment: @bjb568 I'm rolling

Comment: I'll miss you too, Shotgun Ninja, member for 4 years, 8 months and first-time poster. ;p

Comment: @BilltheLizard I believe that's what they call a lurker :P

Comment: Lurking allows users to learn the conventions of an online community before they actively participate, improving their socialization when they eventually de-lurk. However, a lack of social contact while lurking sometimes causes loneliness or apathy among lurkers!!

Answer (score 31):

Congratulations to all.

Mostly as a matter of curiosity, a little while ago I wrote an implementation of [Ranked Pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranked_pairs) extended to multiple-seat elections, and capable of consuming OpenSTV ballot files. I used several previous SE and SO elections as part of my testing data.

I'm pleased to report that the results of the present election using Ranked Pairs are well in agreement with STV, with the top three places going to Martijn, maegar, and Jeremy. Indeed it was a very clear-cut election, with no tie-breaking or cycle-breaking required. In essence, that means that any sensible preference voting system would have given the same results given the same ballots. :)

Answer (score 26):

Having to fill in for Bill the Lizard comes with indeed a big pressure, but I am sure that the new moderators, for what they've shown in the past, have the capability to do a good job. 
I want to thank Bill for the long and awesome he's provided to the community, and I want to wish a good luck for the future to the new moderators.
Long life to SO.

Since Bill will have some more free time now...

[image]

Comment: No picture, no up-vote.

Comment: There you have it @ArunA.S :)

Answer (score 23):

[image: Bill the Lizard]

> **Bill, first and foremost, *thank you for your awesome service to the community*.**

**"Bill" the *Wizard***, err... **"Bill" the *Lizard*** has had been a role model. Now that he has set up an example, it would be a great help for the **`newly elected moderators`** or the **`wanna be moderators`**.

Of course, you will be missed :-(

[image]

Woah, I didn't know **Bill is among the first two moderators**. Now that is an awesome service to the community.

**All the best!!!**

Answer (score 19):

**Thank you Lizard, and welcome to all of you.**

*Coming together is a beginning; keeping together is progress; working together is success.*

Cheers up.[image]

Comment: This one is the most accurate likeness, if anyone was curious.

Comment: Of all the lizard pics, this one looks most adorable.

Answer (score 17):

I am very new to the Stack Overflow community (Not really. I used to use it sparingly and I was a **BIG** noob until now), and I am totally speechless of how people rate you as a moderator Bill. Even with me not being there all the time, I would just like to say: **Thank you for keeping this site running** and have a peaceful retirement and I wish you good luck at your career and I hope you get elected the next year.

[image]

Answer (score 15):

### Dasvidaniya Bill

[image: BILL_THE_LIZARD]

Thank you so much for your service and work here from last many years (even before when I was not born on SO) and also good luck for your new adventures.

## And of course many many congratulations to our new moderators  :)

Answer (score 15):

There are two unusual things I passionately wanna do right now:

```
1) Cry 
2) Give a lizard a big hug!
```

Well done, Mr Bill. I'm aspiring for those big shoes of yours. Hoping to get there before `max_execution_time`! Image downloading... `<img src="big_lizard.bmp" width="inf" height="inf" />` (Sorry sir, my tribute lizard image is too big to fit here, or anywhere).

```
For-Each(new mods) AS new mod:
```

Thanks for offering to serve. More grease to your elbows! And more grease to wherever else it's actually needed on this job: fingers, eyeball muscles, etc.

```
End-Foreach;
```

SO is the `MAX()` thing that has happened to my `{programming}` life, and you guys `#meanging: everyone here in the community` have made it happen.

`Congratulations++`