# Shouldn't there be a special badge or profile emblem for retired moderators?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In the announcement of the [results of the latest election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results?cb=1), there was an announcement of the stepping down of [Bill the Lizard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1288/bill-the-lizard) as a moderator in May.

By recognizing that moderators are doing lots of great work in SO and other sites helping out millions, shouldn't there be a special badge (apart from Sheriff) or emblem on the profile of such users as an honor for their time and efforts given to the community?

Comment: I like this idea.

Comment: [Cross site dupe on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181668/186281)

Comment: There should be some badge or special emblem on profile

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3109/sheriff

Comment: As mentioned in the question, there should be something more special IMO (and more visible) for those who are not contributing anymore, like a "legacy emblem", sheriff is for all moderators that have been active for 1 year, and, although rare, someone must take a look at someone's badges. I am talking about an emblem, like the rhombus of the active moderators.

Comment: How about a unicorn symbol to sum up the power, intelligence, beauty, grace and now mythological aspect of the departed (legendary?) former mods?

Comment: Of course, there would also have to be one for Bad Conduct Discharge and for Dishonourable Discharge.  Unicorn rainbow fart and turd, respectively?

Comment: If the current symbol for moderator is a solid diamond, then perhaps an open (hollow) diamond would be a good symbol for moderators emeritus.

Comment: If we can have adjustable hats in winter (wich almost everyone loves), wouldn't it be possible to have something like that for them? like a star or a badge they could adjust over their profile pic.

Comment: If someone wants to know about my moderator history, I can certainly show off all my scars. No need for a special badge.

Comment: I'd like to suggest name flair of a heart, instead of the diamond. Cause come on, we <3 our mods!

Comment: I didn't even know about that diamond stuff. Where is it explained?

Comment: @Aldian http://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators - the diamonds are mentioned in the last paragraph

Answer (score 136, accepted):

I really think [it needs to continue to be username flair](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181668/allow-ex-moderators-to-opt-in-to-having-a-mark-on-their-profile-indicating-they#comment552420_181668), because a lot of moderation actions result in messages attributed to the moderator, and those messages become very unclear when the diamond mod insignia ceases to be displayed.

One frequently suggested possibility is from

> Bill the Lizard ♦

to

> Bill the Lizard ♢

Comment: perhaps a hollow diamond, greyed out a little

Comment: @artB - animated diamond turning into a pile of dust

Comment: I really hope this answer doesn't get lost amidst the others. It probably ought to be its own feature request if a duplicate's not already out there already.

Comment: Alternatives to ♢ (the white ♦): ◇ or ◊

Comment: Even better: the hollow diamond should only be displayed on actions and comments made while the user was a moderator. That way, it's not just an indicator that they were a moderator in general, but also that they were a moderator *when this happened*.

Answer (score 103):

Yes.  And since

[image: mod monkey meme]

it should be

Pistol emoji (U+1F52B) + monkey face (U+1F435)

[image]
(enbiggened)

Comment: This deserves more upvotes.

Comment: I'd switch them around so the gun is pointing at the target.

Comment: I dunno, I think this is more fitting to replace the diamond with this. Then we could pass the diamond on to the retired mods. Since we've taken the guns from the retired mods.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Unfortunately, every impl of the emoji I've seen points to the left... oh.

Comment: @Kendra taking a moneys gun leaves a diamond? I think it would rather be a monkey.

Comment: Current moderator:  Moderator emeritus:  -- no more gun.  Having this "site specific" would be acceptable (because I could imagine becoming a monkey might be considered offensive on some stack exchange websites)

Comment: Nope, i see a box     with an x through it

Comment: Retired mods ran out of ammunitions.

Comment: @Isaiah what browser what OS? Not that I care, I just want to mock you about them.

Comment: Google Chrome, Nook HD+

Comment: @Isaiah >nook >mfw (protip: your nook doesn't have any of the fonts listed in CSS that has emoji characters. Possibly a [meta-tag:feature-request], but I don't believe they will support it)

Comment: @RippedOff I have seen what's is going on, I just want to say that you were a sunshine of humor and I hope to "work" again with you where ever you go. Thanks for the fun

Answer (score 37):

I agree with this.  Moderators do more work on their own personal time than many users of the site often realize.  While it is just "internet points" recognition for a job well done above and beyond normal community activities is a great idea!

That being said, if we did not want to confuse actual (diamond) mods with (hollow) ones since no actual powers (except perhaps The Force) will be given, we could try something like a new "badge category" in addition to a new badge.

The addition of the "badge category" would mean it would get special attention on the profile as well as the flair but wouldn't confuse users as to it's meaning.  Visually it would be associated with the badges.

For the badge name, I would suggest "Dependable" and for the category I would suggest "Platinum" (I know it's been suggested before) or "Rhodium" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodium)

It could look something like this:[image]

Comment: That diamond with the reputation is actually a good idea.

Comment: @ArunA.S I agree, I like the hollow diamond idea but on MSE there was some debate about this, so I thought this suggestion might be a reasonable compromise. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181668/allow-ex-moderators-to-opt-in-to-having-a-mark-on-their-profile-indicating-they

Answer (score 10):

It would be a great addition to people who have served as moderators and decided to step down for whatever reason to be able to have a badge that shows a users recognition for their contributions to the site.

Something like "`Veteran`" would be an apt badge name maybe? Or "`Seasoned`"

Or even go the whole hog and give them something *like* the diamond next to their name

Comment: The title "Veteran" would reference to the army in a sense as mentioned, and moderators are more of janitors here. I would suggest for a title like "Jedi Master" or "Wise Man" as an alternative, or, if we want to be formal, something like "VIP" or "Exceptional Personality". Also, an emblem reflecting those values would be great too.

Comment: There are many possible badge names, veteran doesn't always mean military related. I do quite like the ring `Seasoned` has to it

Comment: There is already a badge granted only to moderators. Why would anybody need another one? - Could we have some kind of recognition towards them? Sure! Just not a badge, please...

Comment: I don't like "Veteran" - in the US at least it has a strong military connection (though admittedly not here in the UK, where it means "old hand, experienced"). Is there a teacher/professor's hat font icon?

Comment: @halfer Seriously, veteran has multiple meanings; there are no specific cannotations or connections anywhere; it can mean experienced or it could mean war veterans. There is not a problem at all with a veteran badge in tjat respect.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, @Isaiah, though you'd need to expand on that somewhat if you wished to change my view. [See this search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=veteran+united+states) or [even this one](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=veteran) - the commonest usages of the word _overwhelmingly_ turn out to be militarist. (Some of this may just be American appetite for shorthand: "military veteran" to "veteran" to, for the last few decades, "vet". In the UK it is sometimes wondered why veterinarians would need legislative protection from discrimination - we quite like them over here).

Answer (score -46):

The purpose of the diamond is that people understand a moderator's abilities and the fact that they might be able to help you or intervene to enforce policy.

It is not supposed to be something you can wave around. Nor is it the equivalent of rows of medals on the chests of a generals in a military dictatorship.

Therefore there is no need for 'moderators emeritus' to have any special symbol.

Comment: With all the respect, I disagree. The moderators do an amazing job here without any reward apart of the reputation and the badges - and they are people, not machines, having their own lives and familes in parallel. This is not about any military award or medal. It is a way to say "thank you" to someone who has offered much to many of us, as the least we can do for them.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, retiring moderators won't be even marked with diamond. So an extra badge to mark, that they once done a lot of good work for society is quite a good idea.

Comment: @NickL.: Yes we all value the moderators but nothing you just said actually addresses this answer. This question/feature suggestion is not a "who can prove the most that they appreciate the work of moderators emeritus?" post. It's a "is there a hard, _practical_ application for keeping the diamond indicator alongside the names of users?" And so far nobody has been able nor even bothered to try to provide one.

Comment: And no, this "they are people not machines" mantra that seems to be the answer to everything on meta these days, is not sufficient reason to do it.

Comment: "they are people, not machines". [[citation needed]]

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit Ben Voight's answer seems like a good concrete practical reason

Comment: @Frank: Okay granted that one's not bad. But it's still lightyears away from Nick's argument!