# Welcome two new moderators: Matt and Jon!

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-resignation

Moderator [bluefeet has decided to step down in order to pursue a new career](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/06/pivoting-into-a-new-career-please-welcome-taryn-pratt-bluefooted-community-manager/). While we all wish her the best of luck, there's no denying that her efforts will be missed... Especially the hundreds of flags she handled on a daily basis.

Therefore, Stack Overflow needs some new moderators. Fortunately, the two runners-up in [the last election](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291017/april-2015-community-moderator-election-results) have graciously volunteered to step up and attempt to <s>fill her shoes</s> uh, paint their feet blue and hope for the best:

[image: Matt] [image: Jon Clements]

They've [joined the existing crew](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) - please give them your help and support as they undertake this new challenge!

Comment: Congratulations! This is a suprise package for all of us!

Comment: Nice!! Way to go, guys!

Comment: A blue-footed emu? That's a first!

Comment: It takes two to fill her shoes. Awesome.

Comment: Can I say Matt Diamond?

Comment: So they blue themselves?

Comment: High-fives all around!

Comment: @Anna Lear: Emu. It's an emu.

Comment: @BoltClock This is an emutional time for us all. (brb, ninja-editing my comment)

Comment: Welcome to Jon and Matt! And congratulations to bluefeet!

Comment: We have a problem. Birds can't paint. Damn. I failed at the first hurdle of being a moderator :(.

Comment: @Matt You can always just step into a pot of paint.

Comment: Who was the last mod to be appointed in this manner?  Was it me?  If so, watch out for these guys.

Comment: @Will You weren't really appointed, it was more like 'alien abducted'

Comment: At 56 days since the last election, this is the fastest set of battlefield appointments we've yet seen. The previous record was 64 days when jjnguy was appointed in January 2012 to replace Anna Lear.

Comment: @TimPost: No wonder why my butt is in permanent hurt mode.

Comment: @Matt: Drop the modesty. You look **fabulous**.

Comment: I was about to say that bluefeet will be missed. Then I clicked the link.

Comment: @Pekka 웃: But she *will*. I hold a private memorial for all the mods who have succumbed to the same grisly fate that bluefeet has now experienced.

Comment: What happened to Jon's previous avatar?

Comment: Animal avatars > Human avatars. Congratulations, all!

Comment: @TLama: that's been [gone for a little while now](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/22953619#22953619).

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are "the runners up" determined? As a Meek-STV-noob, glancing over [the results](http://www.opavote.org/results/4962933813542912/0) you could as well expect others to be "the runners up" (i.e. by guessing based on either round 1 results or how late they were eliminated). Or did those others pass on the delayed election?

Comment: @Jeroen It appears that SE team re-runs the vote analysis on the same set of ballots, but with more seats. [hichris123 did the same](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3575235#3575235), and the result was "Winners are meagar, Matt, Martijn Pieters, Jon Clements, and Jeremy Banks"

Comment: Ol' Slim is correct, @Jeroen. As always, you can verify our methods yourself by downloading the election data.

Comment: Congrats. Just remember, when the day happens that you have to deal with one of my posts, I'm not irrational, I am slow-rational. :)

Comment: 2 moderators to fill place of 1??

Comment: BTW where has bluefeet going now?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: She is an employee now.

Comment: Awesome! I actually voted for both Matt and Jon. But then again, I also voted for bluefeet some time ago…

Comment: how many moderators are born and bread in Reading? :)

Comment: so StackOverflow pays salary you mean @PatrickHofman

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Yeah, to the developers that actually _work_ for Stack Exchange. Bluefeet was hired to the actual team. Regular mods are volunteers and do not receive pay. Someone has to have the job of keeping all these amazing sites running. :)

Answer (score 173):

Welcome new crew!

Here's ya brooms, there's the pile, better start sweeping!

[image]

Comment: Is that a firsthand experience?

Comment: I'd call it deckhand experience.

Comment: One of them appears to be holding the broom upside down. I'd say this is pretty accurate.

Comment: That crew seems entirely too happy. Looks 'shopped.

Comment: Is it from *[Operation Crossroads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Crossroads#Fission-product_radioactivity)*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: that'd be funny, but no, they are British and not American sailors. Appropriate, since both Matt and Jon are British.

Comment: @TimPost, I can't find the upside down broom, needs a freehand circle I think.

Comment: @Malachi: the one closest to the camera has the bristles pointing up, not down.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, lol I know I was joking.

Comment: @Malachi: I see! Here you go then: http://i.stack.imgur.com/c8ODR.png

Comment: Thank you @MartijnPieters.  :) LOL

Comment: Yay! Now the crew is bigger in size, I better go and add some more flags to the pile :P

Answer (score 108):

Here's an exclusive glimpse at Matt's new kicks!

[image: Matt flaunting his new kicks]

<sup>[Original, unshopped photo](https://www.flickr.com/photos/pierre_pouliquin/111730689)</sup>

Comment: Is that a dark emu with blue legs or a gold emu with white legs? [I can't tell](http://www.theguardian.com/science/head-quarters/2015/feb/27/the-dress-blue-black-white-gold-vision-psychology-colour-constancy).

Answer (score 43):

I completely agree that that it will take **at least two** to replace [bluefeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426671/bluefeet) in a moderator capacity.

As I'm relatively new to SE, she was the first moderator I consciously voted for.

[image]

Comment: Have you been sleep voting?

Comment: We have detected anomalous unconscious voting coming from your account. ***Remain calm***, helicopters have been dispatched to your location, the people with horns are your friends.

Comment: @TimPost Why horned people?

Answer (score 30):

I would like to say Congratulations to the both of you.  You will need this:

[image]

Comment: That seems a little heavy. I prefer the temporarysuspensionhammer.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my way to welcome **Python Lover** [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) who is currently at [Cabbage World](http://sopython.com/)  and mostly talking [at this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python)

```
print("Welcome Jon Clements !!")

$ python3 welcomenote.py
```

And you might feel blue now

[image]