# Refuse questions containing the words "don't work" or "doesn't work"?

Tags: feature-request, questions, content-blocklist

It occurs to me, after years of prompting individual questioners to explain what "doesn't work" is supposed to mean when they complain that something is wrong, that our question submission code, which already vets the question, could just refuse to accept questions containing that sort of thing.

Could such a notion get any traction?

Comment: Filters like these are no pr0blam to bypass.

Comment: I'd personally rather it _prompt_ the user ("Make sure you've explained _how_ it doesn't work!") as part of question review.  I admit to sometimes searching "_____ doesn't work" when I'm particularly vexed by something...well, not working.

Comment: Also worth noting that the phrase doesn't mean the question lacks details: "I used <code> but it doesn't work because <detailed description>"

Comment: The existence of "doesn't work" doesn't guarantee that the question doesn't go on to explain what doesn't work.

Comment: In fact, _you_ have used it [four times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A341994+%22doesn%27t+work%22+is%3Aq), including once [in a title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24125328/208273) ("Swift optional chaining doesn't work in closure").  That's a perfectly fine question (and a good title!), nothing wrong with it.  You'd have to come up with a much more contorted title if this feature request were implemented.

Comment: I'm just going to say it once again: questions should start in a closed state.

Comment: @RyanM Touché! The old _ad hominem_ bait and switch. (And, like you even know what I'm verbally capable of when put to it.)

Comment: That is not an ad hominem argument.

Comment: Why auto-waste a perfectly good downvoting/ closing opportunity?  :)

Comment: @matt uh, what was it that made you think that is an ad hominem argument?

Comment: @justANewbstandswithUkraine "In fact, you have used it four times, including once in a title" That's a _tu quoque_ which is the purest form of _ad hominem_. But I would dispute it; my whole point is that the system should have stopped _me_ from saying "doesn't work" too!

Answer (score 17):

The filter has two problems:

1. It  don  work well to catch stuff. Especially on a user who  [dosnt  spell things correctly on purpose](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256534).
2. It also will catch false positives. The phrases do not necessarily mean the question lacks details. Just to prove a point:

There are 2670 questions with the phrase "doesn't work" in them and a score over 50. [Link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22doesn%27t+work%22+is%3Aq+score%3A50..)

There are 233 questions with the phrase "don't work" in them and a score over 50. [Link to search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22don%27t+work%22+is%3Aq+score%3A50..)

Comment: Addendum: [The title word filter is one of the worst ideas ever implemented on SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112944)

Comment: But it didn't work. Wouldn't work. Will not work. Was not working. Is not working. I thought this should work but it didn't. Etc. etc. Who cares about typos deliberate or otherwise, the English language allows for vast poetic freedom in expressing oneself. There's no stopping this train.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases

> don't work

means just

> results are not the expected ones

By itself, such statement is not a problem.

The difference between good and bad questions which use such statement is whether **expectations are clear** or not.

Common pattern for a bad questions, where expectations are not evident for readers:

> My code <lengthy-code-without-comments> doesn't work. Please, help.

Examples of good questions (selected from the search request from [@VLAZ answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/423454/3440745)):

1. [sudo echo "something" >> /etc/privilegedFile doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work)

   Even without explanations, the title

   > sudo echo "something" >> /etc/privilegedFile doesn't work

   is clear for almost everyone: it is about redirection to a file, which requires sudo privileges for writing.
2. [Remove empty array elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654295/remove-empty-array-elements)

   The question describes both the purpose of the "not working" code:

   > I need to remove those (empty) elements

   and actual results:

   > $linksArray still has empty elements.

   From that description it is perfectly clear which expectations are failed.

For a regex-based filter it is impossible to distinguish clear and unclear expectations.

Answer (score -8):

I'm going to veer into a slightly academic exercise here.

It's very difficult to express your precise pain points.

Think about it - when you first started programming, all you knew was that the code would "not work", for a given definition of work.  You rushed to whomever you thought might have an idea, and you described the issue *exactly* as you saw it.

Someone who's more expert may be able to point out that you forgot about that missing [`T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM`](http://phpsadness.com/sad/1) which is why your code isn't working.  Or maybe it's more subtle; the syntax and compiler/lexer/interpreter are happy but it's not [rounding the numbers right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/1079354).

Describing your problem as you see it is ***just fine*** when it comes to asking questions.  The challenge is, instead of focusing on the exact syntax or delivery of the problem, the OP needs to fill in what their expectations are and what they saw (which answers the "what do you mean by 'doesn't work'"-question).

A filter can't help with that.  Only voting to close and comments ever will.

Comment: "when you first started programming, all you knew was that the code would "not work", for a given definition of work" - disagreed. The hypothetical "you" would know **what is supposed to happen** when the code runs - because otherwise, you would not have attempted to write it. Askers know **what does happen** - because they can and have tried running it, and observed what happens (otherwise, they would have no basis for the "doesn't work" claim). They know **that** this is different, because otherwise they wouldn't have the complaint. We are simply asking them to **describe the difference**.

Comment: IOW: "the OP needs to fill in what their expectations are and what they saw (which answers the "what do you mean by 'doesn't work'"-question)." - **Exactly**. The **point** of such a filter is to *highlight* that OP *has not done so*. The correct objection to this approach is as VLAZ said: regexing the post can't actually verify whether it has been done or not.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel:  You react too viscerally.  Yes, an asker would know what their expectations are of the application when it works.  My perspective is that even though the asker has an expectation of what they want to see, they may not have enough syntax to concisely express that need in such a way that another person who is more expert can action it.

Comment: I fully agree that the OP needs to fill in more details besides "doesn't work".  This is why VTC and comment is a reasonable pattern to follow to prod the OP to fill in the blanks.  What *doesn't* help is some kind of automated *thing* that prevents them from relieving their pain (which only compounds pain, not reduces it).

Comment: "My perspective is that even though the asker has an expectation of what they want to see, they may not have enough syntax to concisely express that need in such a way that another person who is more expert can action it." I agree. However, an "automated thing" could certainly *prompt the asker to try*. Or, at the very least, to *show actual and expected program output*.